# Prove that $\{x: Ax<b\}$ has no extreme points

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, polyhedra

Suppose we have the set {$x : Ax < b$} and we want to show that it has no extreme points. Graphically, and intuitively this would make sense to me because the points of intersection of all the linear equations aren't actually in the set. But I am having trouble showing this mathematically

Comment: Here's a quick approach via topology: the set $S = \{y:y<b\}$ is open, which means that $A^{-1}(S) = \{x:Ax < b\}$ must also be open since the linear map $x \mapsto Ax$ is continuous.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Where does $x$ belong to? What is $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $A$ is a continuous linear map.   We can write $x$ as $\frac {(1+\frac 1 n)x} 2+\frac {(1-\frac 1 n)} 2 x$ and the points ${(1+\frac 1 n)x} $, $ {(1+\frac 1 n)x} $ both belong to the given set if $n$ is sufficiently large. Hence $x$ is not an extreme point.

Comment: Are there any approaches without using the continuity/point set topology machinery?

Comment: No. Strict inequality and continuity of $A$ are important for the result, so topology comes in naturally.  @eggplant